# How do you match [ ] with regex?

Tags: regex

I thought I was doing `\[/b\]`

but the machine disagrees.

Comment: What flavor of regex? And are you writing a literal, or a string that will then be parsed into a regex?

Comment: From what kind of string do want to extract what? Please show a example of your string and what do you want to get as result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ***How do you match `[ ]` with regex?***

`\[ \]` should do just fine. At least in the Java regular expression engine.

```
System.out.println("[ ]".matches("\\[ \\]"));   // prints true
```

---

Not sure where you get the `/b` from. Perhaps you're after a "blank" character. The most common expression for whitespace characters is `\s`. I.e., you could do `\[\s\]`.

---

(Matching *balanced* `[` `]` is another story though. A task which regular expression are not very well suited for.)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer well without knowing *which flavor* of regex you're using, but:

If you're writing a regular expression literal in a language (like JavaScript) that has them, then just put a backslash in front of the `[` and `]`. E.g.:

```
var re = /\[\/b\]/;
```

...creates a regular expression that will match a `[` followed by a `/` followed by a `b` followed by a `]`. (I had to escape the `/` because in JavaScript regular expression literals, of course the `/` is the delimiter.)

In languages where you use a string to specify the regular expression (Java, for instance), escaping can be confusing, because you have to escape with a backslash, but of course backslashes are special in *strings* and so you have to escape them. You end up with lots of them:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[/b\\]");
```

That creates a regex that does what the one above does, but note how we had to escape the escapes.

Answer (score 0):

```
'^[a-z]' // Should do fine in UNIX and possibly PERL/PHP too.
```

Example one with the grep command (similar to find)

```
grep '^[A-Z].?' file.txt
```

Find words that begin with a capital letter and then any characters after whether capitals or not.

Hope that helps.

DL.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?